# How to convert a Visual Studio Setup Project to a ClickOnce deployment?

Tags: visual-studio, clickonce, setup-project

I made a very nice setup project (New Project -> Other -> Setup and Deployment -> Visual Studio Installer -> Setup Project), but I really like the way ClickOnce works.

Sadly I had to use a setup project because of some custom actions and registry editing during installation.

Is there a convenient way to make a ClickOnce deployment out of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use any custom actions in ClickOnce and there is no way to edit the registry with ClickOnce.

If you need these features, ClickOnce will not work for you.  There is no way to convert your deployment.